# Seamless user mobility with wifi and ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, wireless, iwlwifi, hostapd

I am trying to do an experiment using two ubuntu server machines. They are running ubuntu 12.04 and wifi adapters are connected. I made them wifi hotspots using hostapd. Now I have two access points with the same SSID. But I would like to know how to make a device handover between these two access points without any IP change or connection drop.